# how to create data frame from kafka topic for the webserver logs in pyspark structured streaming?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to parse webserver logs from kafka topic.
Below is the script

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


print("Kafka App launched")
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("spark://mymaster:7078").appName("django_logstash").getOrCreate()
#df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myip:9092").option("subscribe", "session-event").option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 10).option("partition.assignment.strategy", "range").load()

df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "myip:9092").option("subscribe", "django-logs").option("startingOffsets", "latest").load()

result =df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")


reuslt.printSchema()

print("Kafka Straming output is",result)
query = result.writeStream.outputMode("append").format("console").trigger(processingTime='30 seconds').start()
query.awaitTermination()
```

Here logs are parsed as string in the batch as

```
Batch 1
Key     value
----    ------
Null    "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2737"
Null    "GET /hydjobs HTTP/1.1" 301 0"
```

#Expected:
I need to create a data frame from above logs by creating a new schema. But since above logs contains different events which are not static, what would be the approach to define new  schema for above logs in such case?

Appreciated for the help?

Thanks

Comment: small typo in `reuslt.printSchema()`

Comment: Hi @mikksu i need to create a new schema for the logs..

Comment: I know, i read your question. Regardless of your intention: in your code is a small typo.

Comment: You could create a new column in which you should parse the event value . Create schema for all these events and parse accordingly. You might be using regular expression and substring methods to extract values